# How to create a box with cut off corner and shadow? (Boxed Website design)

Tags: html, css, shadow

I'm working on a website and I need to cut off the top left corner of the main body.
After that I want to apply a shadow on the main body. This shadow should not go around the original box it should follow the main body with the new cut off corner - I used drop-shadow for this.

I tried using gradient background but no matter what I try my header is either overlapping the main body or the shadows don't work

My current attempt is this: https://codepen.io/Sophvy/pen/MWgMZzG

HTML:

```
<div id ="main1">
  <div id ="wrap"></div>
  <header>

  </header>
  <main>
  </main>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main1 {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
}
#wrap {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 70px,green 0);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px blue);
  position:absolute;
}

header {
  height:55px;
  max-width:100%;
  background-color:#eee;
  position: relative;
}
```

My Issue here is that the header doesn't get cut off so its just overlapping.
I tried using z-index but couldn't get it to work even with position:absolute / relative on each element. I looked at a lot of different ideas but I haven't found any that handle the same problem that I'm having with my header.

What do I need to change to cut off the corner of the main body and the header, and then afterwards get a working shadow?

EDIT: my solution

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
  <div id ="main1">
    <div id ="wrap">
      <header>
        header
      </header>
      <main>
      main
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
  height:500px;
  width:600px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color:#bbb;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#main1 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
  height:400px;
  text-align:right;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px blue); 
}
#wrap {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 70px,green 0);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 25%);
  position:absolute;
}

header {
  height:55px;
  max-width:100%;
  background-color:#eee;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: use clip-path and not gradient .. gradient will not cut, it will color with a transparent color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where very close!

If you use a clip-path you can cut both the header and the main part of the box.
When you then set the drop-shadow filter on the main element you should get the desired style.

```css
#main1 {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px blue);
}
#wrap {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 70px,green 0);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 25%);
  position:absolute;
}

header {
  height:55px;
  max-width:100%;
  background-color:#eee;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id ="main1">
  <div id ="wrap">
    <header>
    </header>

    <main>
    </main>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see how this works but sadly I couldnt use it for my website. I made a new test code that represents my actual website layout more clearly: https://codepen.io/Sophvy/pen/yLLBGba

I'm a bit confused why this doesn't work. since the only thing that really change is that I have a background and then the box in the middle?

Comment: @Sophvy Is that because "main1" is your primary container? I can't really see why you coldn't use this method in your code, sorry. The only thing required for this method to work is that you have two divs around your header and main. The outer div needs to have the filter and the inner one needs to have the clip-path property.

Comment: oki I figured it out was just some small logic error.  thanks for helping :)